# Android Layout Components Unexpectedly Rendered to the Top of the Screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two text views filled with rectangular gradient colors that appear under the a music player.

Here's the layout file: 
    `

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frequency"
    android:text="MIDI Play Back"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<MediaController
    android:id="@+id/mediaController1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timer" >
</MediaController>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="160sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frequency"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mediaController1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mediaController1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/frequency"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" 
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frequency"
    android:text="@string/Timer"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/connectbutton"
    android:text="@string/connect23andme"
    android:textColor="#99FFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_rectangle"
    android:text="@string/risk_score"
    android:textColor="#99FFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageSuffixTextView"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/risk_low"
    android:text="@string/ind_risk_score"
    android:textColor="#99FFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

However, the two text fields are not rendered the same as the one you see in Eclipse once the app runs on the emulator. Specifically, the textview with id=messageSuffixTextView appears on the top of the screen rather than appearing below the textView3.

Just in case they are relevant, here are my gradient drawable files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#0000FF"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

risk_elevated.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFCC33"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

risk_high.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FF0000"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

And risk_low.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#66FF33"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

I really wish that I can upload an image, but I don't think that I have enough reputation.    :(  Please tell me if I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:layout_marginTop="18dp"` from `messageSuffixTextView` ?

Comment: It still appears at the top of the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// I Have modify your code now try it.
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MIDI Play Back"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/frequency"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/frequency"
        android:layout_below="@id/frequency"
        android:text="@string/Timer"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

    <MediaController
        android:id="@+id/mediaController1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/timer"
        android:layout_below="@id/timer" >
    </MediaController>

  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mediaController1"
        android:layout_below="@id/mediaController1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="160sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/frequency"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/connectbutton"
        android:text="@string/connect23andme"
        android:textColor="#99FFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_rectangle"
        android:text="@string/risk_score"
        android:textColor="#99FFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageSuffixTextView"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/risk_low"
        android:text="@string/ind_risk_score"
        android:textColor="#99FFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```